# KO Sortable: <ul> is not tall enough to drop into

Tags: knockout.js, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

HTML excerpt:

```
<div style="height: 80%;" data-bind="sortable: { data: $data.data.sections, connectClass: 'sectionDrop' }">
    <section class="section">
        <div data-bind="text: 'New Section'"></div>
        <ul class="connected" data-bind="sortable: { data: fieldsCol1, connectClass: 'fieldDrop' }">
            <li>New Field</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="connected" data-bind="sortable: { data: fieldsCol2, connectClass: 'fieldDrop' }">
            <li>New Field</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Basically, the user can drag & drop `section`s into the `div`, and then drag & drop `li`'s into each `ul` within the `section`.

I can d&d the `section`s but not the `li`'s. Reason being, the `ul` is not tall enough to be visible. If I set a fixed height for it then obviously it won't expand dynamically.

I'm sure this is extremely easy, but I'm just stuck here. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set a `min-height`?

Comment: No. But it worked! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `height` you need to set the [`min-height` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) to some value.

With using the `min-height` your `ul` will be at least that high but they will expand if the content "grows" inside them.

So you probably need to change your `connected`  class to something like this:

```
.connected {
   min-height: 20px;
}
```